# Regtest setup to analyze the protocol

Tags: network, regtest, performance

I'm currently working on my bachelor thesis in which I have to analyze which are the scalability issues the bitcoin protocol has and try to see how it react changing different parameters ( for example the block size ecc... ).
I have downloaded the entire blockchain and I'm currently setuping a private regtest network. I also have been asked to try to use the real transactions up to next week, "load" them in my regtest mode and start testing on this environment. Is this possible? I mean, is there a way to import the real bitcoin transactions on the blockchain into a private blockchain? Do you know any other solution/advice that could help me perform this task?
Moreover, if you know any interesting article/paper about scalability and blockchain would be really useful.
Thanks everyone! :)

Answer (score 1):

> I mean, is there a way to import the real bitcoin transactions on the blockchain into a private blockchain?

no

Comment: Do you have any advice I could use to do what I need to do?

Comment: you can perform all analysys on testnet chain. i do not see any benefits running private blockchain in your case.

Comment: But if I use the testnet chain I can really modify the protocol itself, can  I?

Comment: I think you do not have enough knowledge to modify anything in protocol. Start with easy tasks.

Comment: Thank for you answer. Could you also explain me why this task is not possible?

Comment: In the end, I completed the task without the regtest mode.